# Find all solutions of $AX=2X$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a linear algebra problem in which I'm asked to find all solutions of $AX = 2X$ with

$$ A= \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 6 & -4 & 0 \\
4 & -2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 3\end{array}\right]$$

But when I try doing it by row reducing, I get some nonsense answers, so I'd like some guidance on how to solve such a problem.

Comment: If $Ax=2x$, then $(A-2I)x = 0$.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: I can, but the book I got this from is doing it right after introducing elementary row operations. What ways  do there exist that don't use the theory of eigen vectors per se?

Comment: None—I think the problem expects you to find the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$, and that is how you do it.  The only difference is the word *eigenvector* isn't being used.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean that that solution uses eigenvectors? It's true that the (non-zero) answers are eigenvectors to $A$ with eigenvalue $2$, but you can't get away from that fact. The proposed solution by @MatthewLeingang is just to solve the equation as a linear equation.

Comment: Is $X$ a vector or some matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the question is answered in the comments, so let me summarize.  To find solutions of $Ax = 2x$, look for vectors in the nullspace of $A-2I$:
$$
    A - 2I = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -4 & 0 \\ 4 & -4 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
The reduced row echelon form of this matrix is
$$
    \operatorname{rref}(A-2I) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
So a vector $x$ in the nullspace of $A-2I$ satisfies $x_2 = x_3$ and $x_1 = x_3$.  Hence $x$ is a multiple of $(1,1,1)$.

You are, of course, correct that the problem is asking for the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$.  But the question can be posed (and answered) without using those words.

Comment: Shouldn't the lower right component of $A-2I$ be $3-2=1$?  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640897/simple-matrix-subtraction-confusion)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are absolutely correct.  I'm sorry for the confusion that three-year old typo caused.  I've updated the $A-2I$ to the correct matrix.  That doesn't change the rref matrix following it, so the final answer doesn't change. (And, one can directly check that $x=(1,1,1)$ satisfies $Ax = 2x$.)