# Find the solution of the following matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Find the solution of the following matrix equation: $Ax = 2x$

While the matrix $A$ is defined as=

\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & -2\\
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & 3 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

Any hint?

Comment: The solution is $\ker(A-2I)$. For example, $X=0$.

Comment: Same question already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166674/find-all-solutions-of-ax-2x).

Comment: Already saw the other one and the answer is not illustrated well, It'll be appreciable if someone solved it with more steps and more illustration. ♥

Comment: You have to practice the Gauss algorithm yourself, if you want to learn it. I got $X=\lambda(1,-1,-1)^T$.

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to solve the following, where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $I$ is the identity matrix:

$Ax-2x=0$

$(A-I2)x=0$

So, you will get  from $(A-I2)$ the matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 0 & -2\\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 3 & -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

Once you did that, you just have to triangulate through the Gaussian elimination and find your $x$

Comment: I did the Gaussian elimination for the matrix and I got some matrix, can you tell me what should I do next? how to find X i mean, if it's multiplied by the Gaussian-eliminated matrix

Comment: Please, put me here the matrix you just got and I will tell you!

Comment: thats what i got \begin{pmatrix}-2&0&-2\\ 0&3&-3\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Okay. Think about this one second: what are you doing when you are applying the Gaussian-elimination?

Comment: You are starting from a system that is formed by a lot of linear equations, in this case, just three, and to solve it, you write the coefficients of that system separately and create with them a matrix. So, in this case you are starting from: $-2x_1-2x_3=0; x_1+x_3=0; x_1+3x_2-2x_3=0$ Do you understand for now?

Comment: Oh yeah that's understandable, I mean that's great till now

Comment: can we chat somewhere else? i'm not that high reputation to chat here im sorry

Comment: Okay, So then, when you apply the Gaussian-elimination to the matrix you formed from the system you had, and you start doing the combinations between the rows, you are simplyfing the original system, to get one easiest, from where you can get the variables you are looking for. So, Finally you got that Okay, So then, when you apply the Gaussian-elimination to the matrix you formed from the system you had, and you start doing the combinations between the rows, you are simplyfing the original system, to get one easiest, from where you can get the variables you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah now i have to solve for X1, X2 and X3 and that will be x as a vector, am i right?

Comment: Then, you got a symplified matrix so a simplifyed system. So, you got $-2x_1-2x_3=0; 3x_2-3x_3=0$ and from here you can look for conditions of $x_1,x_2,x_3$. So you will have: $x_2=x_3$ and $x_1=-x_3$ So, $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(-x_3,x_3,x_3)=x_3(-1,1,1)$ where the solution for $x$ you are looking for is $x=(-1,1,1)$

Comment: Yes! You are right! I hope that what I said have helped you to understand!