# Simple Matrix Subtraction Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations

I am looking at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2166674/find-all-solutions-of-ax-2x) that is causing me confusion but I am not able to comment on it to gain clarification. Within it A is a matrix declared as follows:

$$ A= \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 6 & -4 & 0 \\
4 & -2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 3\end{array}\right]$$

The person who answers the question proceeds to claim that $$
    A - 2I = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -4 & 0 \\ 4 & -4 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is it not supposed to be

$$
    A - 2I = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -4 & 0 \\ 4 & -4 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

and if so why not?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang

Comment: It appears that the person made a mistake.  The lower right component should be $3-2=1$

Comment: With that being said, I then require further clarification in regards to the answer. How would I get there attention? Can I tag them in this post? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get attention, but I left a comment on that answer

Comment: You and @J.W.Tanner are absolutely correct.  It was a simple typo.  I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Because
$$
I_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
each diagonal component should have $2$ subtracted from it; the $(3,3)$ entry has been missed.